# Is this 3/4 at 270 BPM or 6/8 at 90 BPM?

Tags: theory, notation, sheet-music, time-signatures, tempo

So im composing a song called "Consonant Dissonance II" ([You can listen to the first one](https://musescore.com/anything/consonant-dissonance)), and I hear it as 270 BPM 3/4 but I dont know if it is correct to notate it as that. (Sorry if the question is too short but I dont really know how to extend it)

Here is a link to the current progress **(unlisted):** https://musescore.com/user/36283528/scores/6829608/s/z4nUs4?share=copy_link

**EDIT:** I finished the song! (https://musescore.com/anything/consonant-dissonance-2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though you already accepted an answer I’d like to add there is no right or wrong way to notate this as long as you get the desired result when the music is being read. It is your piece so you decide how you feel it and what the meter should be. I believe you made the right call in writing it in 3/4 time, it seems like a frantic waltz to me and 3/4 time fits that, the bass notes feel like downbeats to me.

Comment: I agree, it depends on which beats you'd like to be strong vs weak; but, is it practical to count eighth notes at 270 BPM? (This is an honest question)

Comment: @Giovanni Regardless of whether the piece is written in 3/4 or 12/8 the notes have to be executed at that velocity. The fact that the bars and tempo are slower in 12/8 doesn’t make it easier. There is no need to count eighth notes, on the contrary, when a piece in 3/4 is this fast it can be felt, counted and conducted (if necessary) in “1”, one pulse per measure. I have done this many times when playing in ensembles for musical theater for example, a genre that often has very fast waltzes.